# Py Cord - Send two images to channel at once

Tags: javascript, python, pycord

I am trying to send at least two images to a channel at once however I am having no luck and I can not seem to find anything about it. I am trying to achieve something like this: https://prnt.sc/s7wg9b

```js
async def test(
    ctx: discord.ApplicationContext,
    name: str,
    div: str,
    collar: str
):
    test = make_texture(name, collar, div)


    with open(str(test) + "_black_vest.png", 'rb') as f:
        picture = discord.File(f)

    with open(str(test) + "_black_vest.png", 'rb') as f:
        picture2 = discord.File(f)

    await ctx.send(
        file=picture + picture2
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have two options, how to do it**

1. Simply sending two messages one after another:

```js
await ctx.send(file=picture)
await ctx.send(file=picture2)
```

2. Sending one message with multiple pictures pinned to it, using array:

```js
my_files = [picture, picture2]

await ctx.send(files=my_files)
```

Here are some useful links:

- [py-cord docs](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/index.html)
- [Related part of docs](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/migrating_to_v1.html#sending-messages)